# Cannot compile with openmp

Tags: c++, compilation, openmp

omp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    std::cout << "Hello ";
    std::cout << "World! " << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

I've tried to compile the above code with `g++ omp.cpp -fopenmp` but I get the error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried googling what -lpthread is but I couldn't find anything. The closest thing I found was another thread in which someone compiled his/her code like this: `g++ omp.cpp -fopenmp -lpthread` ... but the result is the same for me.

Am I missing something? Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using openmp on windows with mingw. Cannot find -lpthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554716)

Comment: It works now. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/154524/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pthread` is the POSIX thread library.
`-lpthread` is a linker argument, meaning you are trying to link your binary with `pthread`.

The error means that this library is not available on your OS.

It looks like you are using `mingw` on Windows.
No surprise `pthread` isn't available on Windows, as it's a POSIX library.

But you may find some ways to have it on the MinGW website:
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library

Looks like you'll have to install a third-party library called `pthreads-win32`:
https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Comment: Much appreciated. So I've downloaded 'pthreads-w32-1-10-0-release.tar.gz', but I don't know where to put it. Do I put this folder into my MinGW folder? Perhaps this is too much to ask, but I'm really a newbie in this area.

Comment: You should have a 'lib' or 'usr/lib' directory in mingw, with other libraries. Try to put pthread here, as this dir is likely to be in the linker search paths.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I've tried a couple of things now, but none of them work. Just why is this stuff so complicated. Anyway, I don't want to spam the comment section now. I appreciate your effort nonetheless.