# Why OpenMP doesn't speed up my C program?

Tags: c, performance, loops, openmp, gmp

I'm new with OpenMP and I was trying to use it to speed up my C program (with GMP). The code below is a [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) I've made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int lucas_lehmer(unsigned long int p) {
  mpz_t M, s, t;

  // Let M = 2^p - 1

  mpz_init_set_ui(t, p);

  mpz_init(M);
  mpz_setbit(M, p);
  mpz_sub_ui(M, M, 1);

  unsigned long int I;

  mpz_init_set_ui(s, 4);

  #pragma omp parallel for
  {
    for (i = 3; i <= p; i++) {
    printf("Processed: %d\n", i-3);
    mpz_mul(s, s, s);
    mpz_sub_ui(s, s, 2);
    /* mpz_mod(s, s, mp) but more efficiently done gisen mod 2^p-1 */
    if (mpz_sgn(s) < 0) mpz_add(s, s, M);
    /* while (n > mp) { n = (n >> p) + (n & mp) } if (n==mp) n=0 */
    /* but in this case we can hase at most one loop plus a carry */
    mpz_tdiv_r_2exp(t, s, p);
    mpz_tdiv_q_2exp(s, s, p);
    mpz_add(s, s, t);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      while (mpz_cmp(s, M) >= 0) mpz_sub(s, s, M);
    }    
    }
  }

  int res;
  res = !mpz_sgn(s);
  mpz_clear(t); mpz_clear(M); mpz_clear(s);
  return res;
}


int main() {
  unsigned long int p;
  printf("Enter an exponent:");
  scanf("%d", &p);

  int boolean;
  boolean = lucas_lehmer(p);

  if (lucas_lehmer(p)) {
    printf("\nPrime number: True\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("\nPrime number: False\n");
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I added `#pragma omp parallel for` and `#pragma omp parallel` to see if the performance of the program is improved.

After I compiled with the command `g++ lucas_lehmer.c -lgmp  -I C:/gmp-6.2.0/include/ -L C:/gmp-6.2.0/lib/` (I use MinGW-MSYS), compared to my code without using OpenMP, I found no speedup in my code. What was the problem here? How do I fix this?

- Optional question: The code above seems to have a problem with the loop. It repeats the loop twice before checking. How do I prevent this?

Comment: You need to pass a flag to gcc if you want to enable omp. I don't know if that's supported on windows. Your code is clearly not thread-safe.

Comment: I added `-fopenmp` in my compile command but then another error occurs: `cannot find -lpthread` `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Not having `-fopenmp` was your main problem. Have you tried this for your subsequent issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23638488/11365539

Comment: @Warpstar22 Also do you know how to fix the loop in my code? It repeats twice every time I run

Comment: @KiênP.S. Are you referring to the for loop or the while loop? I'm not well versed in the algorithm you are trying to do so I don't know what you mean by "before checking"

Comment: @Warpstar22 It's the for loop. But I have found a solution: simply delete 2 lines `int boolean;` and `boolean = lucas_lehmer(p)`. Since I've already called the function once in the if statement, having those 2 lines will call the function one more time